# Flutter updated Native App - Problems with duplicate Push Notifications

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, we updated an existing app with an new app written in Flutter. Everything worked great, except for one problem with push notifications.

- For the new app (Flutter), when a user (does not have to be logged in) subscribes to push notifications, the fcm token is stored in a separate list than from the old (native) app
- As it is a gradual roll out, push notifications are send to both lists (old and new app).
- The old (native) app and new (Flutter) app use different Firebase projects

Here is the problem:

- 2 push notifications are sent to the device.

I can't find any info on what's happening with an fcm token when the app is updated.
With the app updates `getToken()` is called on the first app start. Will this 'Flutter' Token be the same as the native 'Android' Token?

- With logged in users we can delete 'duplicate' tokens from the 2 server lists
- But what to do with users that are not logged in. We don't save a device identifier.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As FCM is used , token generation will be same for android and app build with flutter for android. You can do one thing  like compare users from old server and update with new token to old one for the same user. this way it will send to only one. Hope this might help you

Comment: I forgot to mention that we have 2 different Firebase projects.

And how would you compare users if they are not logged in?

Comment: So, you have same project bundle id register with 2 different firebase accounts. it should be only one.

Comment: yes exactly. 
it's a big project and there is politically no other way than having 2 different projects. 
so changing it to one firebase project is unfortunately not an option. 

but thanks for your advice

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer to this? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Late, but yeah. 
So, we didn't find a solution. It's a new device token. We had access to the old code base and saw that the token was saved to the shared preferences and we could then recover it from the storage. 
Hope this helps